# Converting simple returns to monthly log returns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, return, finance

I have a pandas DataFrame with simple daily returns. I need to convert it to monthly log returns and add a column to the current DataFrame. I have to use `np.log` to compute the monthly return. But I can only compute daily log return. Below is my code.

```
df[‘return_monthly’]= np.log(data([‘Simple Daily Returns’]+1)
```

The code only produces daily log returns. Is there any particular methods I should be using in the above code to get monthly return??
[Please see my input for pandas Dataframe, the third column in excel is the expected out.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acEiP.png)

Comment: You should provide an example input/output.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little confusing, but it seems like you want to group the rows by month. This can be done with pandas.resample if you have a datetime index, pandas.groupby, or pandas.pivot.

Here is a simple implementation, let us know if this isn't what you're looking for. Furthermore, your values are less than 1, so the log is negative. You can adjust as needed. I aggregated the months with sum, but there are many other aggregation functions such as mean(), median(), size() and [many more](https://cmdlinetips.com/2019/10/pandas-groupby-13-functions-to-aggregate/). See the link for a list of aggregating functions.

```
#create dataframe with 1220 values that match your dataset
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':pd.date_range(start = '1/1/2019' , end ='5/4/2022' , freq='1D'),
    'Return':np.random.uniform(low=1e-6, high=1.0, size=1220) #avoid log 0 which returns NAN
}).set_index('Date') #set the index to the date so we can use resample

    Return  Log_return
Date        
2019-01-31  14.604863   -33.950987
2019-02-28  13.118111   -32.025086
2019-03-31  14.541947   -32.962914
2019-04-30  14.212689   -33.684422
2019-05-31  14.154918   -33.347081
2019-06-30  10.710209   -43.474120
2019-07-31  12.358001   -43.051723
2019-08-31  17.932673   -30.328784
...
```